# AppHub's reporting tools

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, marketplace

AppHub's reporting tools are very lacking right now (at least for WP7 apps, which is what I'm publishing), I can't see a chart that clearly let me compare the 3 apps I have, I can't see the actual net revenue, I can't easily see in which country the apps are selling more. 
Any way to go around this?
Have anyone written a script or Excel macro to provide more info from the data I can grab on the site?

Thank's
  Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try www.mopapp.com

It integrates with AppHub/WP7 Marketplace, as well as with many other app stores and platforms (iTunes, Android Market, RIM App World, Amazon Appstore, GetJar, Handango, ...)